# HTML, AJAX: two clicks to update different portion of a content. What about css and the second click?

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine

(Re-edited, Nov 23, 2012, because some of the problems are due to my personal errors. Sorry.)

I am developing a web system on Google App Engine. I have a page *base.html* which contains links, each of which when clicked would update **content1** div via Ajax. **content1** is supplied by *admin.html* which contains buttons and **content2** div. The buttons when clicked would update **content2** via Ajax, too. **content2** is supplied by *manage.hmtl* in which there are many forms to collect data one by one.

Here are my problems:

(1) The two clicks on the link in *base.html* and later on the button in *admin.html*, respectively, works just fine -- **content1** shows the buttons and **content2** shows the forms. However, there is no **content2** div in *manage.html*, how would Ajax update **content2** in *admin.html*? Currently, when I post one of the form data, **content1** went blank. I would like it to still show the forms because there are other data to enter.

(2) There are more than 20 links and buttons in the page. Do I have to write 20 Ajax functions for them? Is there a way to write just one (or two) function instead and share by the links and buttons.

Thanks in advance for you help. Descriptions of the program and fragments of scripts are listed as follows:

*main.py* renders *base.html* (includes **content1** div)

URL /admin: class Admin(webapp2.RequestHandler) adds the content of *admin.html* (includes buttons and **content2** div) to **content1** via Ajax

URL /admin?arg1=manage: class Manage(webapp2.RequestHandler) adds the content of *manage.html* (includes several forms) to **content2** via Ajax

Problem: After submitting one of the forms in **content2** (i.e., *manage.html*), the page went blank.

base.html:

```
    <html>
    ...
    <div id="content1"></div>
    ...
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return admin()">Admin</a>
    ...
    <script>
    function admin() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/admin",
            cache: false,
            success: function(returndata){
                $("#content1").html(returndata);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    ...
    </html>
```

'admin.html' (no html header)

```
    ...
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return manage()">
    <img src="/static/images/main-manage.png" class="adminButton" /></a>
    ...
    <div id="content2"></div>
    ...
    <script>
    function manage() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/admin?arg1=manage",
            cache: false,
            success: function(returndata){
                $("#content2").html(returndata);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

'manage.html' (no html header)

```
    <form action="" method="">
    ...
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="button" onclick="return addImage()">
    </form>

    ...

    <form ...>
    ...
    </form>

    <script>
    function addImage() {
        var image = $('input[name=image]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/admin?arg1=manage&arg2=image",
            data: {'image': image},
            cache: false,
            success: function(returndata){
                $("#content2").html(returndata);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: CSS is applied when the page reflows - so added content has CSS applied automatically.

Comment: Please show the CSS for the button issue you are describing.

Comment: What are you debugging with?  Use Firebug on Mozilla, or Chrome's debugger.  If you are looking at the file using "View Source", you will not see content that has been added with Javascript.